# In VB.NET, who can Iet all databases that contain a specific table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

In VB.NET am trying to return all databases that have a specific table.  The code I have been using polls just the databases and that works fine.  When I add the CASE statement below to get just the ones with the table I need then it returns nothing.

```
strQuery = "SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases where create_date > '2016-07-01' and [name] not like '_Config_Options' order by create_date desc"

 sqlCon = New SqlConnection(strConn)
    Using (sqlCon)
        Dim sqlComm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strQuery, sqlCon)
        sqlCon.Open()
        Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader
        If sqlReader.HasRows Then
            While (sqlReader.Read())
                cmbDatabase.Items.Add(sqlReader.GetString(0))
            End While
        End If
        sqlReader.Close()
    End Using
```

The above code returns the full list of databases.

When I change the strQuery to

```
strQuery = "SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases WHERE CASE WHEN state_desc = ''ONLINE'' THEN OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME([name]) + ''.[dbo].[MyTable]'', ''U'') END IS NOT NULL order by create_date desc"
```

I get nothing back.  After executing Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader, the code jumps to the End Using.  I don't see an error code.

Comment: The SQL executes fine in SSMS.

Comment: `WHEN state_desc = ''ONLINE''` Note the double set of single quotes on each end. It should be just `WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE'`

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for finding my mistake.  It works!!!  I had copied code where I needed them previously.

Answer (score 0):

Joel Coehoom gets the credit for answering.  I removed the double single quotes and it works.

```
strQuery = "SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases WHERE CASE WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE' THEN OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME([name]) + '.[dbo].[MyTable]', 'U') END IS NOT NULL order by create_date desc"
```